# how can i change my Node and Python Versions from 32 bit to 64 bit for a web app on azure

Tags: node.js, oracle, azure, botframework, node-oracledb

I am creating a node js web app using bot framework.

For now, I need to install node-oracledb module for making a call to oracle db deployed on remote server.

installing the same with below command

```
npm install oracledb
```

throws following error

oracledb Continuing installation
oracledb ERR! NJS-054: Binary build/Release/oracledb.node was not installed from oracledb-v2.0.15-node-v48-win32-ia32.gz
oracledb ERR! Error: HTTPS request for https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/releases/download/v2.0.15/oracledb-v2.0.15-node-v48-win32-ia32.gz failed with code 404
oracledb ERR! If the error is not network or filesystem related, then review
oracledb ERR! the Python 2.7 and compiler prerequisites in the installation instructions and
oracledb ERR! then install from source code with: npm install oracle/node-oracledb.git#v2.0.15
oracledb ERR! See https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md

As much i know, This module is released for 64 bit only. for installation, I need to update the dependencies (Node and Python) to 64 bit.

Any help to proceed with upgraded node and python ?

Comment: Is your Azure web app running in 32-bit or 64-bit architecture?

Comment: The node-oracledb module (technically it's an add-on) is usable with 32-bit Node.js - but you have compile it yourself.  Only 64-bit pre-built binaries are currently available.

Comment: @juvchan i can change to both option 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: @ChristopherJones can you please provide the link for 64 bit binaries . If possible tell me how can i compile it with 32 bit nodejs

Comment: The node-oracledb [installation instructions](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md) show [how to compile](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#github).  The instructions also talk about how the [binary packaging works](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#3122-manually-extracting-pre-built-binaries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can change python by going to extensions in the web app and then choosing the 64 bit version of python: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/08/04/upgrading-python-on-azure-app-service/

I don't know for node, do not see that as an option.